# pass a id value from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't pass id value from view to controller.

View Page:

```
<form>
  First name; <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="">
  Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname" name="lastname" value="">    
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Inventory/issue/<?php echo $value->firstname; ?>" >PRINT</a>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function issue($firstname){
   $this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($firstname);
}
```

Comment: Read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: first of all remove index.php from your url

Answer (score 1):

You can use codeigniter's URI class.

```
public function issue(){
   $firstname = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($firstname);
}
```

for reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Inventory/issue?firstname=<?php echo $value->firstname; ?>" >PRINT</a>
```

Now in controller you can retrieve the firstname as :

```
$_GET['firstname'];
```

Comment: If it worked for you, please give an upvote as i want to reinstate my question asking ability.

Comment: remove the question mark after echo base_url() 
now once you define a paramater in the url only way to retrieve it is to use $_GET

Comment: or you can use form action and define the url in action with method POST and in the controlelr function use : $_POST['firstname'];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing variable by url , POST values on your form submit..

Change your form to

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Inventory/issue/" method="POST">
  First name; <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="">
  Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname" name="lastname" value="">    
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"  >PRINT</button>
</form>
```

IN your **Controller**

```
public function issue(){
  $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
   $this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($firstname);
}
```

Comment: in form i already use tree button and one of them save button use type=submit.now i want to print pdf file....and call herf=url .pass id value in url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a hidden field in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?=$value->firstname?>">
```

Then in the controller

```
public function issue(){
   $postdata = $this->input->post();
   $firstname = $postdata['fname'];

   $this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($firstname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sending form in wrong way because it doesn't have submit type,
But if you want to pass your data from link like one line in your code

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Inventory/issue/<?php echo $value->firstname; ?>" >PRINT</a>
```

You are sending data to controller named **Inventory** to function named **issue** with parameter first_name 
so now you can see below code elaborate how to get data to controller

```
public function issue($firstname){
   $fname = $firstname;  //Do this
   $this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($fname); // pass variable here
}
```

say `$firstname` stores golam and this name You send to controller's function  but here you are calling model directly `$this->Inventory_model->pick_Issue_model($firstname)` so the model can't recognize where this `$firstname` comes from